# Oracle with Kerberos authentication and Windows 2003 Server as KDC

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle, kerberos

I am running Oracle 10.2 on a Windows 2003 Server SP2 which is also the domain controller on the network. I wish to switch authentication method from NTS to Kerberos.

I have spent a lot of time trying to configure Oracle with Kerberos authentication from the Oracle Advanced Security option from the Net Manager utility. I have disabled NTS so Kerberos is promoted as the preferred authentication method. But as soon as the configuration is saved from Net Manager and I restart the Oracle server service, Oracle will not start. I don't know what Oracle is complaining about, because I don't know where to look for the Oracle error log. My first question is: how can I figure out what's bugging Oracle?

My second question: is there a good tutorial for setting up Oracle on a Windows 2003 with Kerberos Authentication, where the Windows 2003 Server is the KDC? Maybe there is a book I can get?

I have read Oracles own guide, but it is mostly for Linux/Unix.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I actually have been working on this but using windows server 2003 and MySQL.  Here is an article I used except this is the same author who wrote it for Oracle:

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/01/05/connecting-to-oracle-from-sql-server/

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the article you are linking to did not answer my question. To be honest, it doesn't say anything about Kerberos at all.